# How to send a push notification in Ionic via PHP

Tags: php, firebase, ionic-framework

I have succesfully created a pushnotification using Firebase and Ionic 3. I now want to send the notification via my own web application without using The firebase console. Is the there any possible way that i can do that?

Thanks in Regards

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on sending messages through its HTTP API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message and probably many of the questions in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+send).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) has the details for the POST request you will need to make to send the push notification under Send notification. Payload example (REST API). Its as simple as preparing the JSON and hitting the right endpoint with your authorization key.